# How to insert a row of value in a table with python (not Null Values?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlwings

I have a table with multiply lines as follows:

| table1 | col1 | col2 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| row2 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| row3 | 4 | 5 | 7 |
| row4 | 5 | 4 | 6 |
| row5 | 6 | 2 | 3 |
| row6 | 7 | 4 | 6 |

I want to change it like this:

| table1 | col1 | col2 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| row2 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| table1 | col1 | col2 | col2 |
| row1 | 4 | 5 | 7 |
| row3 | 5 | 4 | 6 |
| table3 | col1 | col2 | col2 |
| row4 | 6 | 2 | 3 |
| row5 | 7 | 4 | 6 |

namely,just insert a row(title) to separate it,because they belong to different subtables.
I have try use `insert` function to inert a value of title

```py
d.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, values=["col1", "col1", "col3"], axis=0))
```

but in a specific column of DataFrame, the type of all values must be the same.
I  also use `xlwings` (`insert` function)and `openpyxl` (`insert_rows` function) to insert one row
but it seems that they can only insert with a blank value, not specific values.
After finish constructing this table, I will use it to set some styles.
In excel I just need to copy and paste, is there a flexible way?
or inserting maybe not a good way, and just to split and combine tables(with subtitle and keep format)？

addition:
[data link][1]

[1]: https://cowtransfer.com/s/a160ccec698a48,you need input code 454008

Comment: Is it always going to be every third line?

Comment: Yes, every two lines is a subtable, so I need a title or some text to separate them, otherwise, it may be confused. @not_speshal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
s=pd.DataFrame([df.columns]*int(len(df)/2),columns=df.columns)
s.index=pd.Series(s.index+1).cumsum()
df=pd.concat([df,s]).sort_index().iloc[:-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output of `df`:

```
    table1  col1    col2    col2
0   row1    1       2       3
1   row2    3       4       6
2   table1  col1    col2    col2
3   row3    4       5       7
4   row4    5       4       6
5   table1  col1    col2    col2
6   row5    6       2       3
7   row6    7       4       6
```

**Update:**

you can try:

```
s=pd.DataFrame([df.columns]*int(len(df)/16),columns=df.columns)
s.index=[x+1 for x in range(16,16*(len(s)+1),16)]
df=pd.concat([df,s]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
#If needed to remove last row then use:
#df=df.iloc[:-1]
```

Sample dataframe used by me for testing:

```
import numpy as np
    
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['table1']=[f'row {x}' for x in range(65)]
df['col1']=np.random.randint(1,10,(65,1))
df['col2']=np.random.randint(1,10,(65,1))
df['col3']=np.random.randint(1,10,(65,1))
df.columns=[*df.columns[:-1],'col2']
```

Comment: thx, is the reason that it works is that when the index is that strings sort after nurmeric？
I have tried to do it by myself,if I need to insert this text every 16 rows(this example is every two row), it should set s.index =  pd.Series(np.cumsum(list(range(15,23,1)))),but it doesn't work.I can't get the rule. @Anurag Dabas

Comment: @lemmingxuan yes you can say that this is the idea...If you need to insert this text every 16 rows for that I have to check that and build logic accordingly...so pls wait let me do test

Comment: @lemmingxuan updated answer....kindly have a look and If it helped then try considering giving an upvote.....thnx **:)**

Comment: thx so much, but it seems confused that it can not work well( the location of the text seems a little irregular), I have added data in the question.@Anurag Dabas

Comment: @lemmingxuan updated answer....I have added sample dataframe on which I tested and made a little change in answer.....kindly have a look...btw...the file you provided contains only 6 rows so how you are expecting it to add on  after every 16th row for that your data has at least 16 row present in your dataframe

Comment: thx again. You provide a flexible way. there may be some wrong with the data uploaded. I have solved it in the way that split the DataFrame and use concat function in every part(use a loop).
unfortunately, a DataFrame with different types(strings and numeric) can not be applied to panda's style. Is such a DataFrame is legal？ how to set color and other styles with such a not so standard DataFrame？@Anurag Dabas

Comment: @lemmingxuan sorry sir I don't know much about styling..so I can't help with that **:(**